# Using pretrained model with sample features

Tags: linear-regression, prediction, pre-trained-model

I am new to machine learning, and I have trained a linear regression model.
I have loaded the pretrained model, but I don`t know how to put my features into the model and get the prediction.

I have tried this code and I expected 1 prediction with these 10 features, all this 10 features are what the model needs:
`x = [2.0 , 2.4, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.7, 3.7] linear.fit(x, y) predict_x = linear.predict(x) print(f'Predict = {predict_x}')`
But I got this error:

> Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or          array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: Hey, I have  found the answer:
pretrained_model = load_model('pretrained_model.pkl')

# Example features (replace with your actual feature values)
features = np.array([[feature1, feature2, ..., feature10]])

# Make predictions
predictions = pretrained_model.predict(features)

print("Predictions:", predictions)